# Why doesn't <Link to=...> work, but push() works on production environment?

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I'm using two ways to redirect urls.

One is  component, which is something like

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Link to={{ pathname: "/search" }}>
  <img
    src={image.image}
    alt="product"
    className="slick-image"
  />
</Link>
```

The other one is push() from Redux, which is like

```
import { push } from "react-router-redux";

push(`search/${searchTerm}`)
```

They both are working very well in local environment, but in production environment, `<Link>` doesn't work at all, while `push()` works very well.

Does anyone have any idea why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work at all". Can you include the rendered html output? What is the `href` attribute of the rendered `<a>` element from the Link?

Comment: Sorry for making confusion. When I click the link, the urls shows the correct url that I need to head to, but it doesn't render the component that I see. I checked that href attribute, and it shows a correct href data that I need to have.

Comment: Also, I found that `<Link>` works in Search component, but it doesn't work in StoreDetail component. I guess there is nothing wrong on `<Link>` itself. I guess it's having some conflict with something in StoreDetail component

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to wrap your component with `withRouter` that is usiing `Link`.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
 ...
 ...
render () {
  <div>
    <Link to={{ pathname: "/search" }}>
      <img
       src={image.image}
       alt="product"
       className="slick-image"
       />
    </Link>
  </div>
  }
} 
export default withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

Comment: I tried that, but clicking the link changes the url but it doesn't render the component

Comment: Actually that link redirects to the same component. Does it matter?

Comment: it should not matter, react-router gives a warning when you route to the same url again